# $f'(-1)=3f(2)$ is a subspace of $R^{(-4,4)}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know some have asked similar question some time ago, but I can't seem to find the answer to my question.

The exercise is from "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler.

1.C. 3
Show that the set of differentiable real-valued functions $f$ on the interval $(-4,4)$ such that $f'(-1)=3f(2)$

My problem is then, how do I show the additive identity?

I've found a solution guide saying: "It is clear that the constant function $0$ is contained in $V$"

But why is that clear? I would like to show it, but how?

Comment: If $f(0)=0$ for all $x$ then clearly $f'(0)=0$ for all $x$ and hence $f'(1) = 3f(2)=0$

Comment: f(0)=0 and f'(0)=0 - True
But why f'(-1)=3f(2)=0

Comment: Sorry, I meant $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. Then $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$ and hence $f'(1)=3f(2)=0$.

Comment: Ah of course, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote your set of functions by $V$.

If $z(x) \equiv 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$, then $z'(-1) = 0 = 3z(2)$, hence $z \in V$.

For additive identity, you need to show that if $f,g \in V$, then $f+g \in V$. Let $f,g \in V$, then $f'(-1) = 3f(2)$ and similarly for $g$. Let $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$. Then,
$$
h'(-1) = f'(-1) + g'(-1) = 3f(2) + 3g(2) = 3h(2)
$$
and so $h \in V$.

Comment: I don't understand how this shows that 0 belongs to the subspace.

Comment: @Dorte The second line (regarding $z(x)\equiv 0$) does. Read it more closely.

Answer (score 0):

The *zero vector* of the vector space $\mathbb R^{(-4,4)}$ is the function $\textit{0} : (-4,4)\to\mathbb R$ defined by $\textit{0}(x) = 0$. Well, that function is differentiable and satisfies that $\textit{0}'(-1) = 0$ and that $3\textit{0}(2) = 0$, so, $\textit{0}'(-1) = 3\textit{0}(2)$ and hence $\textit{0}\,$ belongs to the set of all the differentiable real-valued functions $f\in \mathbb R^{(-4,4)}$ such that $f'(-1) = 3f(2)$.

Comment: So for every differntiable function in this interval, the zero vector excists?

Comment: $\mathbb R^{(-4,4)}$ is a real vector space. The zero vector of there is the function that maps $x\mapsto 0$ for every $x\in(-4,4)$. I don't completely understand your doubt.

Comment: I just kind of think it seems to easy, like you know - the feeling, that if something is too easy, you've done something wrong. 

If it was f'(-2)=3f(1) , 
I could still just say 0'(-2)=0 and 3*0(2)=0, and this would show "Additive Identity"

Comment: That is right! That's why the solution guide says *it is clear that the constant function is contained in the set*, because it's clear and easy to show!

Comment: Well thank you!
Then I do understand.